# If $A$ and $B$ are elements of a Boolean (sigma) algebra on $S$ proof that $A \cap B$ is in the Boolean (sigma) algebra.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, logic

I am trying to teach myself a little measure theory and these two questions are exercises that I was given recently. I would appreciate some guidance on how to tackle these questions and if my line of logic is correct.

Q1)

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a Boolean algebra on $S$. Prove that if $A,B\in \mathcal{A}$ then $A\cap B \in \mathcal{A}$.

PF1)

Let $C=A\cap B$ and suppose $C\notin \mathcal{A}$. $\; A\in \mathcal{A} \Rightarrow S\backslash A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B\in \mathcal{A} \Rightarrow S \backslash B\in \mathcal{A}$. This implies that $(S\backslash A) \cup (S\backslash B) \in \mathcal{A} $ by de Morgan's laws this means that $S\backslash C \in \mathcal{A}$.

*I don't really know where to go from here (or even if what I have so far is correct).*

Q2)

Let $\Sigma$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $S$. Prove that if $\{ A_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a countably infinite family of sets in $\Sigma$ then $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \in \Sigma$

PF2)

$\{A_i \} \in \Sigma \; \forall i$ and $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \in \Sigma$.
$\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \subseteq \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \Longrightarrow \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \in \Sigma$

*This seems wrong because it is too simple.*

Comment: I do not understand the question, a Boolean algebra is, by definition, closed under intersection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PF2) is wrong a subset of a set in a $\sigma$-Algebra does not need to be in a $\sigma$-algebra. Look at $A:=[0,1]$ and the $\sigma$-Algebra $\lbrace \emptyset, A\rbrace$ clearly all subsets of $A$ except the emptyset is not in this $\sigma$-Algebra. You have to use the Definition of a $\sigma$-Algebra and De Morgans law to prove this.

According to [Halmos] a boolean $\sigma$-Algebra is a boolean $\sigma$-Ring which is an boolean Algebra.

In [Halmos] a boolean Algebra is defined as

a non-empty class of sets $\mathcal{R}$ such that

(1) if $A,B\in \mathcal{R}$, so is $A\cup B$.

(2) if $A\in \mathcal{R}$, so is $A^c$.

According to this definition youre proof of Q1 is correct, but in my opintion it would be much more straight forward by proving it directly without a contradiction.
The proof of Q2 can be done in the same manner.